# How to get path from file upload input in angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to upload an image and create a preview of it in angular 4. 
The template is given below:

```
<div>
  <input type="file" (onchange)="handleUpload($event)">
  <img [src]="Logo" >
</div
```

I want to call a function `handleUpload()` whenever a file is chosen. This function sets the value of the variable `Logo` to the path of the file chosen. I am not able to get the path because the function `handleUpload($event)` is not called. 
The component class is given below:

```
 export class App {
 Logo:string;

 handleUpload(e):void{
    this.Logo = e.target.value;

 }

  constructor() {

  }
}
```

I don't understand what is wrong with my code. [**Demo**](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZroQeV?p=preview)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In angular you write javascript events without the "on" suffix.

Change:

```
<input type="file" (onchange)="handleUpload($event)">
```

To:

```
<input type="file" (change)="handleUpload($event)">
```

Answer (score 8):

Show preview image - Example code

```
<input type="file" (change)="showPreviewImage($event)">
<img [src]="localUrl" *ngIf="localUrl" class="imgPlaceholder">



 localUrl: any[];
    showPreviewImage(event: any) {
        if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = (event: any) => {
                this.localUrl = event.target.result;
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
        }
    }
```

[Demo and more info](http://www.angulartutorial.net/2018/01/show-preview-image-while-uploading.html)

Answer (score 0):

get full path of selected file on change of  using Javascript,Typescript,Angular.

```html
<input type="file" class="fileControlInput" multiple="multiple" accept=".png,.jpge/*"
       (change)="getFiledetials($event.target)" />
```

```js
getFiledetials(element) {
   console.log(element.value);
}
```